# Android example, "Layout Tricks: Merging Layouts" not working

Tags: android, android-layout, merge

Just looking for some help.  Please let me know if this is too vague.

I'm trying the "Merging Layouts" example found here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

and I can't seem to get it to work.  The source download on the page does not include all the files needed.  I'm pasting some code below with blocks commented out.  When these are un-commented, I receive a ton of errors.  If anyone has a suggestion before I start pasting errors, that would be great...

OkCancelBar:

```
package com.example.android.merge;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class OkCancelBar extends LinearLayout {
    public OkCancelBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setWeightSum(1.0f);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.okcancelbar, this, true);
        /*
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OkCancelBar, 0, 0);

        String text = array.getString(R.styleable.OkCancelBar_okLabel);
        if (text == null) text = "Ok";
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_ok)).setText(text);

        text = array.getString(R.styleable.OkCancelBar_cancelLabel);
        if (text == null) text = "Cancel";
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_cancel)).setText(text);

        array.recycle(); 
        */

    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:okCancelBar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.merge">

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/golden_gate" />

    <com.example.android.merge.OkCancelBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:paddingTop="8dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:background="#AA000000"
        <!--
        okCancelBar:okLabel="Save"
        okCancelBar:cancelLabel="Don't save" 
        -->
        />

</merge>
```

Comment: Could you post the errors? It helps a lot when trying to determine the problem.

Comment: Would you like to share zipped file to somewhere else for me to download? The page says "Error 404 File not found". Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into zipped sources and there is no res/values/attrs.xml file. That's strange.
Create attrs.xml file and put the code listed below:

```
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="OkCancelBar">
        <attr name="okLabel" format="string" />
        <attr name="cancelLabel" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

It should work now, but I haven't time to test it, sorry.

Comment: Also, the .zip was missing these files as well, okcancelbar_button.xml and okcancelbar.xml.

Comment: @Hello Worked Can you give what should i have to do in okcancelbar.xml can you show me it will help me.

Comment: this is so retarded that the source examples from the official blogs are not working....

Answer (score 2):

It is missing a couple of files in that example. Namely:

Under layout folder:
it should have main.xml, okcancelbar.xml, and okcancelbar_button.xml.
Under values folder:
it should have attrs.xml

The contents for main.xml and okcancelbar.xml have been provided in the sample article.
The okcancelbar_button.xml needs to define one button as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
</Button>
```

And the attrs.xml should provide label definition:

```
<resources>
     <declare-styleable name="OkCancelBar">
        <attr name="okLabel" format="string" />
        <attr name="cancelLabel" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then everything should come together.

Answer (score 1):

pawelzieba's & x-ray's  answer is correct also look into this modification.

Put following code into okcancelbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Modify OkCancelBar.java as per following for better understanding

```
public class OkCancelBar extends LinearLayout 
{
    Context mContext;

    public OkCancelBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setWeightSum(1.0f);

        mContext = context;

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.okcancelbar, this, true);

        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.OkCancelBar, 0, 0);

        String text = array.getString(R.styleable.OkCancelBar_okLabel);
        if (text == null) text = "Ok";
        //((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setText(text);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_ok)).setText(text);

        text = array.getString(R.styleable.OkCancelBar_cancelLabel);
        if (text == null) text = "Cancel";
        //((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setText(text);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_cancel)).setText(text);

        Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_cancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Cancel is Clicked...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okcancelbar_ok);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "OK is pressed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        array.recycle();
    }
}
```